# MapKit in iPhone: how to show grouped annotations?

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I would like to create an iPhone app that shows the map of the United States with annotations in different cities. When I zoom in a zone I would like to see annotations in single places (e.g. I see NewYork: 10 pictures, then I zoom in NY and I see 6 annotations in Central Park and  4 in 5th.avenue).
Has anyone already made a similar thing (like in the iPhone Photo application)?

Thanks in advance and greetings!